# Curvature of locally conformally-flat manifolds and pull-back metrics.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature, conformal-geometry, diffeomorphism

Suppose $(M^n, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\forall p\in M$ there is a nbhd $p \in U$ and a local diffeomorphism $\phi:(U, g|_U) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \delta)$, where $\delta$ is the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $g|_U = \phi^{*}\delta$.

Let $R_g$ be the curvature tensor of $g$, then for each $p\in U$ and $X,Y,Z,W \in T_pU$ we have

$R_g(X,Y,Z,W)|_p = R_{\phi^*\delta}(X,Y,Z,W)|_p = (\phi^*R_\delta)(X,Y,Z,W)|_p = R_\delta(\phi_*X,\phi_*Y,\phi_*Z,\phi_*W)|_{\phi(p)} = 0$

because $R_\delta = 0$ since $(\mathbb{R}^n,\delta)$ is flat. This is what I think a locally-flat manifold is, is this logic correct? (As an aside: if we can do this in a nbhd of each point, isn't the whole manifold $M$ flat then?)

Now suppose instead that we have $(M^n,g)$, $p\in U\subset M$, and a local diffeomorphism $\phi:(U, g|_U) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \delta)$ such that $(e^{2f} g)|_U = \phi^*\delta =:\tilde{g}$ for some positive $f\in C^\infty(U)$. Then the curvature tensor of $\tilde{g}$ satisfies (I don't know how to do the Kulkarni-Nomizu product in latex so I just use wedge)

$R_{\tilde{g}} = e^{2f}(R_{g} - (\nabla^2 f)\wedge g +(df\otimes df)\wedge g - \frac{1}{2}(g\wedge g))$

and by the above, this should **still** vanish on $U$, right? This is what I think a locally conformally-flat manifold is.

If I have this correct then on $(U, g|_U)$ we should have $Ricci = Scal = 0$ since $R=0$. But now think about the round sphere $(\mathbb{S}^n,\mathring{g})$: it is locally conformally-flat by using the stereographic projection, and the pull-back of $\delta$ is conformal to $\mathring{g}$ so shouldn't $R_{\mathring{g}} = 0$?? Shouldn't it have vanishing Ricci and scalar curvatures too? I know it certainly does not have those tensors vanishing but I can't understand what's going on here.

I'm asking a lot of vague questions and this reflects my real confusion but if I could try to summarize my question it would be: **Why doesn't the pullback metric under a conformal diffeomorphism have vanishing curvature tensor? Or does it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the aside, "flat" and "locally flat" are often used interchangeably to refer to your definition, but there is also a stronger condition of "global flatness" which requires all holonomy groups to be trivial (or, equivalently, the existence of a parallel global frame). Throughout, I'll talk only about the local case, so every statement need only hold locally.

Note that a metric $g$ has vanishing curvature $R_g=0$ if and only if it is locally the pullback of a Euclidean metric in the manner you describe. Either of this could serve as the definition of flatness, but I'll use only the former condition for simplicity.

By definition, a metric $g$ is conformally flat if there exists a conformally related metric $\tilde{g}=e^{2f}g$ with $R_{\tilde g}=0$. This does not mean that $R_g=0$, since conformally related metrics do not have the same Riemann curvature. The Ricci and scalar curvature will also differ in general (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Conformal_change_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000005A-QINU%60%22%27%7F)), but the [Weyl tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) will be the same.

Using the example of the stereographic projection $\sigma:S^n\setminus\{p\}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, we have the round metric $\mathring{g}$ and the pullback of the Euclidean metric $\widetilde{g}=\sigma^*\delta$ on $S^n\setminus\{p\}$, which are conformally related. The pullback metric has vanishing curvature $R_{\widetilde{g}}=0$, but the round metric has curvature $\mathring{R}_{abcd}=\mathring{g}_{ac}\mathring{g}_{bd}-\mathring{g}_{ad}\mathring{g}_{bc}$